# Topology on set of equivalent mesaures

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, duality-theorems

Let $(\Omega,\mathfrak{F})$ be a measurable space and let $X$ be the set of all probability measures on $(\Omega,\mathfrak{F})$.  Then fix a probability measure $\nu$; i there a topology that we can put on $(\Omega,\mathfrak{F})$ making the set
$$
Y\triangleq \{ \mu \sim \nu \},
$$
closed?

Where two measures are said to be equivalent if and only if $\mu \ll \nu\ll \mu$; that is both measures are absolutely continuous with respect to each other.

Comment: What you can do is consider the topology determined by taking the complements of equivalence classes to be an open sub-base. This is (from definition) the the topology with the "least amount of open sets" so that these sets are closed.

Comment: Ya I thought of this, but this may not be a "nice topology" and then I would have to determine all its properties from scratch (might be a side-track from a research point of view)